# Displaying relative concentration (heatmap) of point features in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, heat-map, kernel-density

I'm pretty new to GIS.

I have a large dataset of point features, all within a arbitrary geographical area (in this case, the greater San Francisco Bay Area). The point features have no other information besides lat/long.

What I want to do is display them in such a way that I can easily see concentrations. I *think* what I'm looking for is called a heatmap, although I've also seen things like "kernel density", "point density" and other terms.

The base of my map is several layers I got from a large dataset. That means that I don't really have a polygon layer that is just the area I'm looking at - the main layer is a polygon feature class of counties in the Western United States.  I could extract just the counties I'm interested in if that would make this process easier.

I'm looking for something like the images in dkwiens' post in this **[thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43069-How-to-create-a-heat-map-from-shapefile-data)**.

What do I need to do? The simpler the explanation, the better - I've spent quite a while on Google looking for this, and while I've found a lot of stuff that seems like it's what I want to do, I haven't been able to translate it to my problem.

---

I should mention that I think the closest I've gotten is with the point density tool. I set the "input point features" to the layer containing my points, the "Population" field to NONE (the other options are X and Y), and a cell size of 50. I've tried several values of Radius, both in map units and in cell units (whatever that means!). After running the tool, I get a layer that looks like the attached screenshot. But nothing actually shows up on the map.
Here's the screenshot:

[image]

---

I noticed that when I look at the generated "File GeoDatabase Raster Dataset" in ArcCatalog, the preview tab has nothing in it - just a blank white screen. Not sure if it's supposed to be like that or not.

Comment: Is this the tool you are looking to use, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000000s000000?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not sure if that's the right tool. I've tried it, and I get a similar result as the screenshot of the result of the point density tool - it creates a new layer, but nothing shows on the map.

Comment: Try creating a population/count field and put a value of 1 for each feature, then run the tool.

Comment: Same result - a new layer but nothing added to the map. Based on my reading of the docs, a population field should not be necessary anyway. If the Population option is set to None, it will just count each point once (which is what I want).

Comment: Check that your point data should be defined in a projected coordinate system and not a geographic one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand that - isn't lat/long data by definition a geographic coordinate system?

Comment: I tried to recreate the feature class from my original XY table, but this time choosing a projected coordinate system (the same one that my CA counties layer is in). However, now my point features are in the wrong spot - they're all displayed in one spot, about 3 counties to the east of where they should be.

Comment: Whenever you are running any mathematical operation on geographic data your layer needs to be defined in projected coordinate system (PCS) and not geographic coordinate system (GCS).  You cannot calculate distance between lng/lat values.

Comment: If your xy data is in lng/lat create the event layer in GCS WGS 1984 (data frame defined as GCS WGS 1984).  Then you can re-project that layer to a PCS using the Project tool.  After that try running the kernal tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my comments above:

When running a spatial analysis tool on geographic lng/lat tabular data follow these steps:

1. Make sure your data frame is set to GCS WGS 1984
2. Create your x/y event layer
3. Export your event layer out to a new layer (to data frame spatial reference)
4. Re-project your layer to a PCS using the [Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000) tool
5. Run your spatial analysis tool (e.g. Kernal Density)